# what is the alternative of giving a nested query in where clause returning more than 1 values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

what is the alternative of giving a nested query in where clause returning more than 1 values in mysql?

the query iam using for just a single value is

```
Select * 
from libertymutual.echi_filtered 
where anslogid = 2984012 and CallTime is not null 
order by CallTime limit 2,1;
```

and i need to get it for multiple `anslogids` from the other query which is

```
Select anslogid 
from libertymutual.echi_filtered 
group by anslogid
```

which should return the 3rd call for every agent when sorted by CallTime.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show us your example data and query.

Comment: Please explain more elaborately.

Comment: `JOIN` ... that's what you looking for

Comment: `JOIN`, `IN`, `EXISTS`, ... There are plenty of alternatives, but which one to use is situational.  We would need to see your query, and know what you're attempting to do to give you a recommendation.

Comment: the query iam using for just a single value is 
`Select * from `libertymutual.echi_filtered` where anslogid = 2984012 and CallTime is not null order by CallTime limit 2,1;` and i need to give multiple anslogids from the other query which is `Select anslogid, from `libertymutual.echi_filtered` group by anslogid`

Comment: @MAK EDIT your question with this information (Edit link is under the tags).  Putting it in a comment makes it difficult to follow.  It will improve your question for others as well.

Comment: i have updated the question, please check